# uploading video to googlevideo.com

Tags: video

may be this question sound stupid , but i really need the answer.

i need to know how to upload video to googlevideo.com like this url :

```
https://r2---sn-4pgnuhxqp5-jb3s.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&id=0e6dae5cec7a2ec7&itag=18&source=picasa&ip=139.195.1.7&ipbits=0&expire=1441333608&sparams=expire,id,ip,ipbits,itag,mm,mn,ms,mv,pl,requiressl,source&signature=57A0DD8FA2F30B7B5350FC9B56A8B27F59E2BDB2.1200B725730532D65C51D7DA2C07ED815CB10604&key=cms1&cms_redirect=yes&mm=31&mn=sn-4pgnuhxqp5-jb3s&ms=au&mt=1441306732&mv=m&pl=19
```

where to upload the video so i can use googlevideo ?

thank you before , hope someone can help me with good answer.

Answer (score 2):

[googlevideo.com](http://googlevideo.com) is a reserve domain of google for store video from youtube.com, when you upload any video via you tube then its automatically store in googlevideo.com server with unique url, and if you can find that unique url from you tube then you will be able to download video from you tube without any software like idm. IDM(A world famous download manager) dose same for download videos from you tube. Hope you will find it useful.

Here is a address from youtube

```
https://r1---sn-gwpa-jj0e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?upn=c2Pk5fXG2R0&expire=1468792420&sparams=clen%2Cdur%2Cei%2Cgir%2Cid%2Cinitcwndbps%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Ckeepalive%2Clmt%2Cmime%2Cmm%2Cmn%2Cms%2Cmv%2Cpl%2Crequiressl%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&gir=yes&key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&initcwndbps=657500&ipbits=0&fexp=3300117%2C3300134%2C3300161%2C3312772%2C3313268%2C9416126%2C9416891%2C9422596%2C9428398%2C9431012%2C9433096%2C9433380%2C9433946%2C9435526%2C9435876%2C9437066%2C9437552%2C9437742%2C9438278%2C9438663%2C9439652&itag=137&mt=1468770476&clen=2411301232&requiressl=yes&sver=3&signature=0A948A23ECC0D20F24FEF63B402E96EEB4EEDEE6.2611D287402F44157AC1FA4D0B9AF888CED95D30&id=o-AKYYEiam4ygTvbv7h7auqJUoDAehrOA_oyYTdsUfTMBo&mm=31&mn=sn-gwpa-jj0e&ei=BKqLV5DLEo2jogOY1ITAAg&keepalive=yes&ms=au&source=youtube&mv=m&dur=9221.600&pl=36&ip=2405%3A204%3Ab083%3A3322%3A308b%3A3b3a%3A89b8%3A9d6b&lmt=1458312382599171
```

Comment: how to generate it?

Answer (score 0):

It's done through https://picasaweb.google.com/.

Just check the "pagesource" after you upload and open the video you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could use vlc player to stream youtube vids and than save them in a playlist some of the file options hold the google.play links if im not mistaken